# Forcing a workstation to use nearest WAP?

Tags: cisco, wireless

I have a workstation in a branch office, there is a WAP about 10 feet overhead and down one row he should be connecting to.  Unfortunately, his workstation is repeatedly connecting to another WAP in another wing of the building.

What does one do in this situation to ensure his workstation is joining the most optimal WAP?

Equipment involved are Cisco AIR-1142's functioning autonomously w/ no WLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you enter the WAP *Radio MAC* (not the LAN/Wired MAC) in the client's configuration (if available, the option depends on the drivers)

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Some drivers permits the user to specify to which Wireless MAC (which AP's RF MAC address) they are to be associated with.

It's often an advanced option, when it's available at all.

Comment: Will this impact their ability roam around the office while traveling to other meeting rooms nearer to other AP's?

Comment: Well, you're forcing them to connnect to a specific AP, so yes it could (depending if the driver only "prefers" the specified one or forces connection only to that one)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the SSIDs are the same and there are no authentication issues, it is up to the client to decide which WAP to associate with. You might see if there's an updated driver for your workstation.